# pandas str.replace value of a column from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am kinda lost here, I am trying to replace a part of the str within one column that is matching value from a separate column.

This is what i have so far

```
    brand       product           
0   BestBrand   prA by BestBrand    
1   newBrand    prB by newBrand 
2   GreatBrand  prC by GreatBrand
```

and I need something like this,

```
    brand       product             newProductName
0   BestBrand   prA by BestBrand    prA
1   newBrand    prB by newBrand     prB
2   GreatBrand  prC by GreatBrand   prC
```

Tried these methods,

```
h = new_file.brand
new_file['newProductName']=new_file.product.str.replace(h, '')

new_file.loc[new_file['newProductName'], 'product']= new_file.product.apply(lambda x: x.replace(h, ''))
```

Comment: Explain us how you got newProductName? So we can recommend a pandas way.

Comment: newProductName is a new column label

Comment: Why isn't there a `by` newProductName ???

Comment: just a string "prA by BestBrand"

Comment: If you replace `BestBrand` by `''`, how can `by` get replaced too?

Comment: just want to clean it, so no 'by' is needed

Comment: Well just do `df['new'] = df['product'].str.split().str[0]`, there is ambiguity in replacement logic.

Comment: problem is that I cannot do .replace("BestBrand", "') since df.brand could be something else, so i really need is something like these ("df.brand", "')

Comment: str[0] is not gonna work, what if brand is 3 or 4 words

Comment: Check out the answer

Comment: I did, you are just indexing the list and getting the first item, however i need to match the string from a ['brand'] column and get rid of the brand in the ['product'] column

Comment: Dude, if you look down thats what I did. Do try it out. I would love to hear from you after trying the solution below, in the answers section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and `replace` i.e

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['product'].replace(('by '+x['brand']),''),1)

     brand           product   new
0  BestBrand  prA by BestBrand  prA 
1  BestBrand  prB by BestBrand  prB 
2  BestBrand  prC by BestBrand  prC
```